# Google Script App : How to transfer datas with the form of the data to another sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, data-transfer

So I want to transfer datas from a sheet to another sheet.
With that code, I transfered datas that i want to, but the problem is that I dont have the color, and the borders of the cells.

```
function copypaste(sourcelink, sourcesheet, soucerange, destilink, destisheet, destirange) {

  var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sourcelink);

  var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName(sourcesheet);

  var range = sheetraw.getRange(soucerange)

  var data = range.getValues();

 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(destilink);

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(destisheet);

 

  sheet.getRange(destirange).clearContent();

  sheet.getRange(destirange).setValues(data);

  }

 

function run() {

  copypaste("link",

            "Planning EDMZI",

            "G10:JE130",

            "link",

            "Planning Export",

            "G10:JE130")

}
```

So, I dont know if it is possible to tranfers datas with the form of the data from a sheet to another sheet.

The color is not the same for each cells, sometime the cell dont have any color, and oher times the cell have a specific color, but that will depend of what the user enter in the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sheet.getRange(destirange).setValues(data);
sheetraw.getRange(soucerange).copyTo(sheet.getRange(destirange), {formatOnly:true})
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE, here is the answer of my question :
I added that line to my code :

```
var bg = range.getBackgroundObjects();
```

And I added that to my code :

```
sheet.getRange(destirange).setValues(data).setBackgroundObject(bg);
```

With that i have the data of each cells and the color that correspond of each cells :)